# REST API to pass indexed parameters for error messages

Tags: java, rest, error-handling

I'm designing a client and server system exchanging information using REST API. For i18n, the client to localized while server is always in English. In order to do that, only error code is sent from server to client and client will pick up the correct version of localized error message to display to the user.

Some error messages require indexed parameters. E.g. error message is "Can't find {0} on server {1}". I'm wondering what's the best practice to pass these indexed parameters (i.e. {0}, {1}) along with error code to the client so that the client can create the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you simply pass the errorcode + parameters in a single JSON object (or xml)?

```
{
   "errorCode": "123",
   "parameters": ["param0", "param1"]
}
```

Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the suggestions from [Nottingham & Wilde](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-http-problem-03).

"This document defines a "problem detail" as a way to carry machine-readable details of errors in a HTTP response, to avoid the need to invent new error response formats for HTTP APIs."